# Odd convert_timezone behaviour in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following issue, I wish to have events converted into a local_timestamp so I can run bucketing/cohorts however when I try to do a convert_timezone, I get `Unknown timezone` error. I tried TO_CHAR & TRIM too, didn't work. See screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, indeed the support helped and told me that in December 2020 this is expected to be fixed. A workaround of my problem was as follows:

```
CASE
WHEN geo_timezone = 'Europe/Saratov' THEN 'Etc/GMT-4'
WHEN geo_timezone = 'Asia/Atyrau' THEN 'Etc/GMT-5'
WHEN geo_timezone = 'Asia/Qostanay' THEN 'Etc/GMT-6'
WHEN geo_timezone = 'Asia/Yangon' THEN 'Asia/Rangoon'
WHEN geo_timezone = 'Asia/Famagusta' THEN 'Asia/Nicosia'
WHEN geo_timezone = 'America/Nuuk' THEN 'America/Godthab'
WHEN geo_timezone = 'America/Punta_Arenas' THEN 'America/Santiago'
ELSE geo_timezone END
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce it using following script. This is known and is happening for specific timezones value and I would suggest to log a support case.

```js
create or replace table timezone_tbl (timezone_ varchar(50));
     
     insert into timezone_tbl values ('UTC'),('Asia/Yangon');
     
     select * from timezone_tbl;
     
     select distinct timezone_, convert_timezone(timezone_,current_timestamp::string) 
     from timezone_tbl;
```

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to log a support case.

Comment: I deleted my post, as with multiple values in the table, it does seem to be an issue.